# Can't delete file after downloading

Tags: c#, file, download

Why can't I delete files after downloading them?

I get this error:

> file 'exfile.jpgg' because it is being used by another process.

Here is my code,

```
string file_name = "pic.jpg"
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://picture.com/pic.jpg", file_name);
client.Dispose();
client = null;

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(File_Name);
pictureBox1.Image = null;

FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo(File_Name);
MyFile.Delete();
```

Comment: Are you doing *anything* else with the file before trying to delete it? If so, please post that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dispose the `Image` object.

> The file remains locked until the
>   Image is disposed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check who has unclosed hande to this file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to close the WebClient first as it would have a lock on it. Perhaps using

```
WebClient.Close() or WebClient.Dispose()
```

Hope this gives you the hint and helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Or use the using directive in order to not forget to close/dispose the webclient:  
using (WebClient w = new WebClient()) {
w.DownloadFile("http://file.com/exfile.jpg", "exfile.jpg");
}

Comment: I don't believe WebClient has a Close method?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some more code. Seems like if you were reading from the file as

[WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

That you are not closing the stream/reader. This will hold onto the file, and will not allow you to delete.

Comment: I am trying to delete files using this:
FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo(@exfile.jpg);
MyFile.Delete();

Maybe this part is wrong ?

Comment: Why not System.IO.Path.Delete(...)?

Comment: System.IO.Path' does not contain a definition for 'Delete'

Comment: System.IO.File contains Delete